# Extract user-friendly error message from entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following code inside my asp.net mvc web application :-

```
try
            {
                var count = repository.changeDeviceSwitch(s.Switch.SwitchID, (Int32)s.GeneralSwitchTo, User.Identity.Name.Substring(User.Identity.Name.IndexOf("\\") + 1));
                repository.Save();
                return Json(new { IsSuccess = "redirect", description = Url.Action("Details", new { id = s.GeneralSwitchTo }) }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

            }
            catch (DbUpdateException exception)
            {
                return Json(new { IsSuccess = "custome", description = "Error occurred." + exception.InnerException.InnerException.Message.ToString() }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return Json(new { IsSuccess = "custome", description = "Error occurred." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
```

which will call the following repository method :-

```
 public int changeDeviceSwitch(int fromID , int toID, string username)
        {

            var currentdevices = tms.TMSSwitchPorts.Where(a => a.SwitchID == fromID);
            int count = 0;
            foreach (var d in currentdevices)
            {

                DeletePort(d, username);
                //d.SwitchID = toID;

                count++;

            }
            foreach (var d in currentdevices)
            {

                TMSSwitchPort tsp = new TMSSwitchPort() { SwitchID = toID, TechnologyID = d.TechnologyID, PortNumber = d.PortNumber };
                InsertOrUpdatePort(tsp, username);

            }

            return count;

        }
```

Currently if the DbUpdateException happen the user will get the following information :-

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_SwitchPortServer'. Cannot
>   insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.TMSSwitchPorts'. The duplicate key
>   value is (1484, e). The statement has been terminated.

this exception will happen when the user try to add a port number that already exists under the same record. (SwitchID + Portno) combination are unique inside database. which is purely technical message , so i am not sure if there is a way to extract a more user friendly error message from entity framework? or i need to do the check by myself ?

Answer (score 1):

How about throwing your own exception?

```
try
{
    InsertOrUpdatePort(tsp, username);
}
catch (DbUpdateException e)
{
    throw new Exception("Friendly message here", e)
}
```

Better yet is to define your own exception class to use here, instead of just `Exception`.

Comment: but the DBupdateException is somehow general and might be raised for different reasons ,, so writing my own error message might not be valid for other reasons,, what do u think?

Comment: @johnG, you are right. There is no way to change what is thrown form DB though. Actually I just though of another kind of logic here. If you expect something like this to happen - then it is not an exception, meaning you should probably do the check yourself. However you can do the check inside the `catch` above - that will make sure you are checking only if necessary

Comment: and what if the uniqueness check fail , what kind of message i should be returning ? let say i will check if the Portno+SwitchID already exists inside my repository method , how i will be passing this error to my action method ?

Comment: @johnG, when it comes to inter-layering messaging, there are various designs out there. On one project we have DB layer returning not object itself, by custom `OperationResult<T>` with fields Result, Error etc. If this is overkill in your situation - consider exposing this check as an API action could call before calling update function. Then everything can be decided on the action level